# Como recibir peticiones https en una aplicacion con Express que preaviamente recibe http?

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo una aplición de backend que subi a una instancia de ec2 de aws. Asimismo, tengo una aplicacion de react.js que hace peticiones al backend. Durante desarrllo el cliente ha hecho peticiones http a la instancia en ec2 sin ningun problema. Sin embargo, despues de subir la aplicion de react a un s3 bucket, tengo que configurar el backend para que pueda recibir peticiones https. Me gustaría saber cuales son las  opciones que tengo y como implementarlas a partir de donde se encuentra mi codigo backend. Se que puedo usar un proxy server o usar un modulo en express para obtener un "ssl certificate".
Este es mi index.js en la aplición backend hosteada en ec2:

```
const express= require('express')
const app=express()
require('dotenv').config()
const cors=require('cors')


app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('app is running in port', process.env.PORT)
})
const whiteList= ['http://localhost:3003']
const options={
    origin:(origin, callback)=>{
        if(whiteList.indexOf(origin)|| -1){
            callback(null,true)
        }else{
            callback(new Error('not allowed'))
        }
    }
}
app.use(cors(options)) 
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'))
app.use('/dashboard', require('./routes/dashboard'))
app.use('/admin', require('./routes/admin'))
app.use('/adminpanel', require('./routes/adminPanel'))
app.use('/sittingPost', require('./routes/sittingPost'))
```

Ahora  bien este es un ejemplo de una funcion que hace una peticion a ese servidor mediante el metodo fetch:

```
//.env
REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER = https://elastic ip address to ec2 instance
```

```
//app.js
const remoteServer = process.env.REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER
const localServer = 'http://localhost:3000'

//check if there is an authorization on token on the local storage

const isVerified= async()=>{
try {

  const response= await fetch(`${remoteServer}/users/verified`,{
    method:'GET',
    headers:{token:localStorage.token}
  })
```

Si tengo que agregar algo para que puedan darme una mejor respuesta, dejenme saber en los comentarios. Gracias